# Asking an amusing, but only very loosely on-topic question?

Tags: discussion, policy, asking-questions

I've got a question which is only loosely related to mathematics, and I don't know the proper place in which to ask. While it's a question I've previously [posed on Twitter (in 2009)](http://twitter.com/#!/john_q/status/1596553571); I think with it being related to mathematics, I'd want to pose the question in a math forum.

My question then is: which six characters look best for a vanity plate: ABLIAN, ABEL'AN, ABEL-AN, or some other combination? (Characters like the ' and - don't count).

[image: ABLIAN License plate]
[image: ABEL'AN License plate]

Obviously I commute... Is this a question which would be unwelcome in the math.SE world? Where should I turn for great mathematical minds applied to a trivial question? :-)

Comment: This is something that is more suitable for the Chatroom...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fun isn't necessarily wrong, but the question you want to ask yourself is

> What could I, as a mathematician, *learn* from this question?

related:
 http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: This was a great response that really in the one sentence states the purpose of the community. And citing an article which says, "A world without fun is like a world without waffles and ponies." wins bonus points. :-)

Answer (score 11):

This is a site for math questions, not for all questions related in some way to math.  In my opinion your question is not on-topic for this site, loosely or otherwise.